# How to debug JSP pages with Tomcat?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is there any way to debug **JSP pages** with tomcat ??

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can put tomcat on remote debug mode. To debug in IDE's like eclipse or netbeans. There is a tutorial over here.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing

Comment: Also from Eclipse (and probably most others) you can launch tomcat as a debug directly rather than remotely connecting.

Answer (score -2):

we can find out on which line our jsp got failed to execute by giving this statements

*<%System.out.println("can be executed until this line");%>*

at the random places in our jsp page and we can easily find out where the error occurs.

Comment: In case of worst case, this can be helpful (ex:if there is no IDE)